# excel VBA Code works when stepping in but not when running live

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have the below line which is failing when I run it live, but when I break the application before this line, it works fine.

```
I = InStr(html_document.body.innerHTML, "EPG")
```

I is a long, is initialized, and should work fine.
html_document is IE.document, initialized through

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
```

Putting a breakpoint before this line makes it work, I picks up the correct character location.

Putting a breakpoint after this line, `I` remains as 0.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to load before getting the html_document? e.g. after using `IE.Navigate` you need to do something like `Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

Answer (score 2):

You're best using the `READYSTATE` enumeration to check that the page has actually loaded.

```
'READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
'READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
'READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
'READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
'READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4


Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
'// your other code here
IE.Navigate "http://www.google.co.uk"

While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

'// Following code will only run once the document has completely loaded.

Set html_document = IE.Document
I = InStr(html_document.body.innerHTML, "EPG")

'// rest of your code here....
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible that your IE Object is not fully loaded, meaning your "I" variable will not be able to get a value.
You could try adding a verification beforehand:

```
Do While IE.busy
   DoEvents
Loop
```

I've had a similar problem with VBA when trying to paste something and finding out that the application wasn't ready to do so. Something that helped me was creating a function to perform the task similar to this:

Declare a constant at the beginning of your module for milisseconds:

```
Const ms As Double = 0.000000011574
```

Then try adapting this for your needs:

```
Function Try_Something() as Boolean
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Application.Wait Now + ms * 50

        'Do something here, such as checking if the value is obtainable'
        var = InStr(html_document.body.innerHTML, "EPG")

    Try_Something = True
    Exit Function
errorHandler:
    Try_Something = False
End Function
```

What this function does is encapsulate the runtime error, should it happen, and adds a delay of 50 ms between consecutive attempts, usually enough to make your code run smoothly. After this, your original code would look a bit like:

```
Do until Try_Something = True
    DoEvents
Loop
I = InStr(html_document.body.innerHTML, "EPG")
```